# Exchange token from AWS Cognito to AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm preparing my degree thesis ( focuses on cloud computing ) so I'm a student and not expert at all my apologies if the question looks stupid.

I'm building a serverless architecture based on NodeJS and Javascript ( back-end and front-end ).
I'd like to manage the user through AWS Cognito.
I've configured my user pool and the GUI in order to register a user or allow the user to use an identity provider like Facebook or Google ( auth login ).

I'm stuck because after the user clicks on the Facebook login I'm able to retrieve the token in my callback page ( it looks like xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx ) but if I try to use that token as "Authorization" in the header in order to access to an API ( AWS API gateway ) I'm getting an unauthorized request.

I've understood that I need to exchange this token with a valid AWS identity token but I'm not able to understand how to do that in JS with AWS JS SDK.

I've found a couple of examples online that uses username and password, but if I don't have those data but just the token that comes from Facebook or Google how can I grab the AWS identity token?

I'll really appreciate if someone can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just give up :(

I did everything ( hosting + authentications + serverless functions + database ) in less than 1 hour with google Firebase.

Wasted 4 days trying to figuring out how to connect all the AWS services without success.

If you are looking for a fast and complete serverless solution I suggest to take look at Google Firebase.

Comment: Don't give up! Look at this course https://www.udemy.com/aws-serverless-a-complete-introduction/learn/v4/overview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Facebook and Google with Amazon Web Services you should know about [Amazon Cognito Federated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html)

Amazon Cognito Federated Identities enable you to create unique identities and assign permissions for users. Your identity pool can include:

- Users in an Amazon Cognito user pool
- Users who authenticate with federated identity providers such as
  Facebook, Google, or a SAML-based identity provider
- Users authenticated via your own existing authentication process

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) but I'm not sure how this works :(